# Motion in oscillating field: expanding in powers of $\xi$

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, linearized-theory

I'm reading an excerpt from Landau/Lifschitz's Mechanics book about motion in oscillating fields. Two equations for the motion of a particle with mass $m$ are set out:

\begin{equation}
m\ddot{x} = -\frac{dU}{dx} + f
\end{equation}

where $f = f_1 \cos{\omega t} + f_2 \sin{\omega t}$ and

\begin{equation}
x(t) = X(t) + \xi(t).
\end{equation}

Then it says:

> Substituting eq.2 into eq.1 and expanding in powers of $\xi$ as far as the first-order terms, we obtain:
>   \begin{equation}
> m\ddot{X} + m\ddot{\xi} = -\frac{dU}{dx} - \xi\frac{d^2 U}{dx^2} + f(X,t) + \xi\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}.
> \end{equation}

My question is, what do they mean when they say "expanding in powers of $\xi$ " and how is the actual substitution carried out more specifically?

Comment: They mean a [Taylor series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can see how to get the left-hand side from the given substitution.  The right-hand side is basically just a Taylor series, assuming that $x \gg \xi$:
$$
-U'(x) = - U'(X + \xi) = - \left[ U'(X) + U''(X) \xi + \frac{1}{2!} U^{(3)}(X) \xi^2 + \dots \right]
$$
$$
f(x,t) = f(X + \xi, t) = f(X,t) + \left. \xi \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right|_{X,t} + \dots
$$